# Functionality, Differences and Similarities between Events and Threads (Java)?

Tags: java, multithreading, events

The thing, I only know is, both functionalities behave very similarly each other.
But I don't know exactly what they do when they are executing.

**And I wanna know how we implement our own event listeners as well.**

Functions like, addListner in JavaFX.

```
@FXML
private TextField textField;

// Listen for TextField text changes
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
            String oldValue, String newValue) {

        outputTextArea.appendText("TextField Text Changed (newValue: " + newValue + ")\n");
    }
});
```

Comment: Events and threads are quite different concepts. I think the only way that they could be compared is that event handlers are executed on a separate, Swing handled thread.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Events and threads may be two totally different things, but the original problem that multi-threading was meant to solve is the same problem that event-driven programming solves. It's _[concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing):_ How can one program manage several different internal activities at the same time when those activities are not strictly synchronized with each other?

Comment: Re, "...And I wanna know how..." That's a separate question. You should post it separately, and you should flesh it out with a description of the problem that you are trying to solve by implementing your own event listener.